# analyze() missing one positional argument: 'request'

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fast-ai

I'm trying to send an image URL

```
var photoData = $("#photo").attr("src");

// console.log(photoURL);
console.log(photoData);

var data = photoData;
$.post("/analyze", data)
      .done((prediction) => {
           console.log('success')
      })
```

to this route using Flask Python

```
@app.route('/analyze', methods=['POST'])
async def analyze(request):
    predictionRaw = learn.predict(open_image(get_image_files(request)[0]))
    prediction = str(predictionRaw)
    return prediction
```

`learn.predict()` uses Fast Ai library. For the Python code, I actually follow [this code](https://github.com/render-examples/fastai-v3).

But for some reason it always gives me this error `analyze() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`.

Why did that happen and what did I do wrong? I'm pretty sure I have sent the request argument using the JS Ajax correctly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 46, in __call__
    start_response)
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\apanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: analyze() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas I just edited my question with the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `request` in the url.  It comes within the request automatically. Try:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/analyze', methods=['POST'])
def analyze():

    print(request.get_data()) # to see what you're sending

    predictionRaw = learn.predict(open_image(get_image_files(request.data)))
    prediction = str(predictionRaw)
    return prediction
```

Comment: It works, I guess? There's no traceback error anymore on the output terminal, but on the browser console I get `POST http://url/analyze 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)` error.